# How to get JMSType in ActiveMQ Artemis via JMS?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I have code that looks at a message and tells me its type (text or byte). I don't understand why my message type outputs `null` and not `text` or `byte`.

```java
Enumeration<Message> messageEnumeration =  queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
while (messageEnumeration.hasMoreElements()){
   messages.add(messageEnumeration.nextElement());
}
System.out.println(messages.get(0).getJMSMessageID());
System.out.println(messages.get(0).getJMSType());
```

Console output:

```
ID:55350491-5216-11ee-8196-f832e49e9cfd
null
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you expect the value returned from `getJMSType` to represent the underlying data type of the message. However, this is **not** what `getJMSType` returns. The "JMSType" is an arbitrary value set by the client when sending the message.

Notice that [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSType--) for `getJMSType()` states:

> Gets the message type identifier **supplied by the client when the message was sent**. (emphasis mine)

Furthermore, the documentation for `setJMSType(String)` states:

> Some JMS providers use a message repository that contains the definitions of messages sent by applications. The JMSType header field may reference a message's definition in the provider's repository.
>
> The JMS API does not define a standard message definition repository, nor does it define a naming policy for the definitions it contains.

If you want to detect the underlying data type of the message you can use `instanceof` along with the various [`Message`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html) implementations, e.g.:

```java
if (messages.get(0) instanceof TextMessage) {
   System.out.println("This is a text message");
} else if (messages.get(0) instanceof BytesMessage) {
   System.out.println("This is a bytes message");
} ...
```